# Why does the compiler implicitly convert a double to int when an explicit user-defined operator exists from int to Foo?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Why is an explicit conversion from `double` to `Foo` possible, even though `Foo` only defined an explicit conversion from `int` to `Foo`?

Why is in my case `double` implicitly converted to an `int`?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double doub = 15.7;
        Foo foo = (Foo)doub;
        Console.WriteLine(foo.value); //writes "15"
    }
}

struct Foo
{
    public int value;
    public static explicit operator Foo(int val) //no matter if implicit
    {
        return new Foo { value = val };
    }
}
```

Comment: thats explicit. if you try `implicit operator Foo(int val)` you will see that you cant write `Foo foo = doub;`...

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary This code is causing error. http://ideone.com/ttBLLX But with 'public static implicit operator Foo(int val)'  'Foo a = (Foo) doub;' works

Comment: The given answers are good. For more information see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/04/16/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/04/18/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c-part-two/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/04/20/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c-part-three/

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is layed out in section 6.4.3 of the C# 5 Language Specification.

A first hint is given in section 6.2.8 User Defined explicit conversions (emphasis mine):

> A user-defined explicit conversion consists of an **optional standard explicit conversion**, followed by execution of **a user-defined implicit or explicit conversion operator**, followed by another **optional standard explicit conversion**

Notice how not one but potentially *three* conversions occur.

Now, to know what is a 'standard explicit conversion' we have to look at section `6.2.3 Standard explicit conversions`:

> The standard explicit conversions are all standard implicit conversions plus the subset of the explicit
>   conversions for which an opposite standard implicit conversion exists. In other words, if a standard implicit
>   conversion exists from a type A to a type B, then a standard explicit conversion exists from type A to type B and
>   from type B to type A.

And looking back at section `6.3.1 Standard implicit conversions` we can see that this is a part of it:

> - Implicit numeric conversions (§6.1.2)

In other words: an explicit numeric conversion (like `double -> int`) can be applied before the user-defined conversion.

If we now look at `6.4.3 Evaluation of user-defined conversions` we see the following (emphasis mine):

> **First, if required, performing a standard conversion from the source type to the operand type of the userdefined or lifted conversion operator**
>
> Next, invoking the user-defined or lifted conversion operator to perform the conversion.
>
> Finally, if required, performing a standard conversion from the result type of the user-defined or lifted
>   conversion operator to the target type.

Which is exactly what happens in your scenario.

Comment: In fact you can get up to *four* conversions by involving nullable conversions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/04/16/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c/

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure if that counted as a conversion considering the C#LS mentions it as "*For the purposes of this step, if either the source or target type is a nullable-type, their
underlying type is used instead*". Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

The relevant section of the C# specification is

- [6.4.4 User-defined explicit conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691303%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The section is lengthy, but it distills to this : you are defining an explicit conversion with `(Foo)doub`, and since you are using an explicit conversion the compiler will choose the most specific available conversions, including conversions that are explicit-only, to make the intermediate steps along the conversion path (if they are available).

> If U contains exactly one user-defined conversion operator that
>   converts from SX to TX, then this is the most specific conversion
>   operator. If no such operator exists, or if more than one such
>   operator exists, then the conversion is ambiguous and a compile-time
>   error occurs. Otherwise, the user-defined conversion is applied:
>
> **If S is not SX, then a standard explicit conversion from S to SX is performed.**
>      The most specific user-defined conversion operator is invoked to convert from SX to TX.
>      If TX is not T, then a standard explicit conversion from TX to T is performed.

(emphasis mine)

Here `S` is the source type and `T` is the destination type, while `SX` is the most specific source type defined in the explicit operators of the destination type (ie; `Foo`) and `TX` is the most specific destination type defined in the explicit operators of `T`.

Here an explicit conversion exists from `double` to `int` and it is therefore chosen as the most appropriate to convert from the source argument type (`double -- S` ) to the input argument type of the explicit operator (`int -- SX`).  It does not need to be explicit since you have already been explicit about making the conversion to `Foo`.

This only works because there are no ambiguous alternatives.  If you defined `Foo` to have :

```
struct Foo
{
    public int value;
    public uint uvalue;
    public static explicit operator Foo(int val)
    {
        return new Foo { value = val };
    }


    public static explicit operator Foo(uint val)
    {
        return new Foo { uvalue = val };
    }
}
```

for example, this produces a compile-time error (with the same `Main`) of :

> Error  1   Ambiguous user defined conversions 'Foo.explicit operator Foo(uint)' and 'Foo.explicit operator Foo(int)' when converting from 'double' to 'Foo'

Again, this is by the book (per the first paragraph quoted above) since the set of available conversions `U` now contains two equally valid explicit conversions and the compiler cannot decide whether you intend to invoke the `int` conversion or the `uint` conversion.  In the inital example there is only once choice, and it is clear, so the compiler takes it.